# Import error: Anaconda numpy (numpy and Anaconda already installed, virtualenv)

Tags: python, numpy, sh

I have a virtual environment my_env in which I installed Anaconda. When I type

```
which python
```

I get:

```
/user/pkgs/anaconda2/envs/my_env/bin/python
```

I have no errors importing numpy here:

```
(my_env) user@hostname:~/my_dir$ python
Python 2.7.12 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:42:40) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>> import numpy as np
>>>
```

But when I say 'import numpy as np' in a python program and run that from a shell script, I get:

```
(my_env) user@hostname:~/mydir$ ./program.sh 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../python_program.py", line 3, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

How can I fix this?

EDIT: I was asked what is in program.sh. The short answer is that I'm running different parameters in a loop. The long answer is:

```
#/bin/bash

i=0
while read a1 b1 c1 d1 e1 f1 g1 h1 i1
    do
    i=$(($i+1))
    mkdir RUN_EXP$i
    cp $a1 RUN_EXP$i
    cd RUN_EXP$i
    ../python_program.py --filename $a1 --reps $b1 --pop $c1 --susc $d1 --exp_trans $e1 --inf_period $f1\ $g1 --eps $h1\ $i1
    cd ..
    done < readparas.txt
```

The file readparas.txt has lines containing filename, reps, pop, susc, exp_trans, inf_period, and eps like this:

```
run_1.txt 50 162 0.30 0.1 5 9 0.1 0.25
run_1.txt 50 162 0.30 0.3 5 9 0.1 0.25
...
```

Comment: What is in `program.sh`?

Comment: @DYZ please see edit above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your shell script doesn't care about having a `virtualenv` active (it starts in a clean environment).

Instead of `../python_program.py` you need to have the full executable path

```
 export PYTHON_ENV=/user/pkgs/anaconda2/envs/my_env

 $PYTHON_ENV/bin/python ../python_program.py --filename $a1 ...
```

---

Or you can append this to the top of `python_program.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Refer: [The importance of env (and how it works with virtualenv)](https://www.peterbe.com/plog/importance-of-env)

Comment: Why is the full executable path necessary? It wasn't with a similar program I ran before.

Comment: Because you are using a `virtualenv` where `numpy` is installed at. Your other program was using your system Python and had all the modules available.

Comment: Except the problem is also happening outside the virtualenv.

Comment: Yes, the error happens outside the virtualenv because you don't have `numpy` there. You need to tell your script which `python` executable needs to run your code.

Comment: @StatsSorceress To clarify: your shell script starts up a new, cleaner, shell environment. It does *not* inherit all PATH settings from the standard shell you issue your `python` command in, hence you need to specifically use that path to the virtualenv Python

Comment: @StatsSorceress You sure about that? Otherwise, you would have no `ImportError`. You might have it installed from Python2, but not Python3, or you aren't using Anaconda libraries as your `python` that is executed on your `PATH`.

Comment: @cricket_007 Thank you, I completely missed the addition of 'env'. I apologize for the misinterpretation! I've accepted your answer.

Comment: I just recently added it